# MIPS code , execution terminated with errors?

Tags: c, mips

I want to make an array of 6 elements , by for loop the user will enter the value of the element each time , then by for loop add each element with 4 and print it .

This is the code it gives me "Go: execution terminated with errors."

```
.text 

#Show the Hello Message :D

li $v0 , 4      #4 because it is a string , 1 if it is integer message , V0 is function register
la $a0 , Message    #add the Hello message in the reserved assembler register a0
syscall         #execute the V0 --->4 function with a0 parameter

#for loop to take the values
add $t0,$zero,$zero

For :
    slti $t1,$t0,24
    beq $t1,$zero,Exit

    #Display Prompt message
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, Prompt
    syscall

    #Get the iput
    li $v0,5    #5 for int input
    syscall 

    #Move the input from the the function to a register

    move $t2,$v0

    add $s0,$zero,$t2
    #save value to the array
    sw $s0,MyArray($t0)

    addi $t0,$t0,4

    j For

Exit:       # End for loop

    add $t0,$zero,$zero

    addi $t4,$zero,4
While:
    beq $t0,24,Exit2

    lw $t6, MyArray($t0)

    addi $t0,$t0, 4

    add $t6,$t6,$t4     
    add $t6,$t6,$t4
    add $t6,$t6,$t4
    add $t6,$t6,$t4


    li $v0 , 1
    move $a0 , $t6
    syscall 


    li $v0 , 4
    la $a0 , Space
    syscall 

    j While

Exit2:


    li $v0 , 4      #4 because it is a string , 1 if it is integer message , V0 is function register
    la $a0 , Message2   #add the End message in the reserved assembler register a0
    syscall         



.data #This for all the data for the program like variables in c++

Message : .asciiz "Hello world !\n" #Display this message on the simulator
MyArray : .space 24
Prompt : .asciiz "Enter the value\n "
Message2: .asciiz "End world !\n"
Space : .asciiz " , "
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. Your code basically adds 16 to every element of the array.

Error you're getting is caused by bad alignment of memory. When you're loading word from memory which is 4 bytes in MIPS32, the address needs to be divisible by 4. To guarantee this in mips your data section you need to add *.align 4* before declaring your array.

```
.data #This for all the data for the program like variables in c++
   Message : .asciiz "Hello world !\n" #Display this message on the simulator
   .align 4
   MyArray : .space 24
   Prompt : .asciiz "Enter the value\n "
   Message2: .asciiz "End world !\n"
   Space : .asciiz " , "
```